# How to update marker without reload google map in swift 5

Tags: swift, google-maps

Hell sir,
I have used google map in swift 5. I have added marker dynamically but my marker overlap the certain time. My marker data come every 10 second. I have stop reload google map. But marker is not update. Here is my image 
[image]
I have used bellow code to add multiple marker.This loop run every 10 second. Update data come after 10 second. But my marker is overlap.

```
  for x in data{
    let marker = GMSMarker()        
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(x.lat, x.lng)
    marker.title = description
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "my_icon")
    marker.map = mapView
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
}
```

How to update my marker without updating google map. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Create an array

```
var arr = [GMSMarker]()
 for x in data{
   let marker = GMSMarker()  
    arr.append(marker)
```

then change it anywhere